# How to obtain per_page number of a Model in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

The number of items for a page in Kaminari is defined by:

1. defining per_page member in model, or
2. defining default_per_page in config.

My question is, how to obtain that number of items in view?

**Update**

Pardon me for being not clear. What I want is to show is the order of item in each page. I have a table header:

```
<th>#</th>
```

And several columns below:

```
<td><%= (@sales.current_page - 1) * some_ruby_code + index + 1 %></td>
```

My question is what `some_ruby_code` should be?

1) If I substitute `some_ruby_code` with `Sale.per_page`, it will throw error when I decided to delete `per_page`.

2) If I substitute `some_ruby_code` with `Kaminari.config.default_per_page`, it won't show the proper value when I add `per_page` in model.

I want to know whether there are a method in Kaminari which detects the existence of `per_page`, return its value if exists, or `Kaminari.config.default_per_page` otherwise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Sale.default_per_page`.

See https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/blob/1-0-stable/kaminari-core/lib/kaminari/models/configuration_methods.rb#L16

Answer (score 3):

You can use ActiveRecord's `limit_value` method for this, since Kaminari internally uses limit and offset.

```
User.all.limit(10).limit_value
=> 10
```

With kaminari is the same:

```
User.page(3).per(10).limit_value
=> 10

User.page(3).per(10).offset_value
=> 20
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you want to display the number of items visible out of the total,

if so you can use

```
<%= page_entries_info @items %>
```

Read this documentation on github:

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid this is not the answer I need. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have the items for that page being rendered in the view, this should work:

`@items.length`

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid this is not the answer I need. I have updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

`current_per_page` returns of given list of paged records.